# Drupal CMIS Alfresco-link issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, alfresco, cmis

I am getting the following error when I try to update or add contents to alfresco via         drupal.

- Notice: Undefined index: workspace://SpacesStore/2e3ea968-07ec-48c8-8295-80bfbef554d6 in CMISService->getLink() (line 421 of /home/drupal/myra/sites/all/modules/contrib/cmis/cmis_common/lib/cmis_repository_wrapper.php).
- HTTP call to [http://myra-dev-repo.bmi.utah.edu:80/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/2e3ea968-07ec-48c8-8295-80bfbef554d6/content] returned [500]. Response: Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error The Web Script /alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/2e3ea968-07ec-48c8-8295-80bfbef554d6/content has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error. 500 Description: An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.   Message:11212017 Failed to execute transaction-level behaviour

I understand that the problem is with the getLink() method which is returning an index of the workspace where the data needs to be saved.But I am unable to figure out where the change has to be made.Moreover this is a new error that has popped up recently.I remember not changing/updating anything : - ( drupal or alfresco setup) that was working just fine.
Please let me know what is going wrong.Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the version of Alfresco, version of Drupal, and version of the Drupal CMIS mod you are using? Also, does this fail for all folders or just this folder? Maybe it is a permissions problem.

Comment: True it was indeed a permissions problem. There were two users,admin and one other user and the content was supposed to be owned by the other user.This was causing the problem and I realised thiswhile  I was updating alfresco and drupal.

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad you got it working. Please respond to your own question and mark it "answered".

Comment: I have a new problem now..I have the latest version of CMIS and drupal 7. The problem is that when I update/add new content , the content switches to plain text from full html when cron runs.I am suspecting cmis to have something to do with it? Any thoughts on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem arises only if the permissions are messed up within the server.So proper attention needs to be paid to, when the content is edited/added/modified etc